# Can Windows 10 download Windows 8.0 app from Store?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-10, windows-store

I have my Windows 8.0 packages in my Windows Dev Center dashboard. I would like to know if there's a way a Windows 10 user to see and download my app from Windows Store. It seems it isn't working.
How to do it? Do I have to "retarget" my project to Windows 10?

Comment: Please un-accept my answer, as I would like to delete it. If you look at the comments, there is some controversy about whether it is correct. I apologize for any trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Windows 10 devices will not be able to see Windows 8.x apps in the Windows Store.

I have the same issue in that I only target Windows 8.x.  I contacted MS support, and they say that you will need to create a Windows 10 package.  This is the response in an email I received from them:

> I understand you are not seeing your app listed in the Win 10 Store. I've taken a closer look and I see that your app is only built for 8 and 8.1. In this situation, you would need to submit a new update that includes a Win 10 package so the Store can begin to offer it.

---

Update - For context, I am including the full exchange here between myself and MS support. I do not have the original text for the *first* support request, but the rest of the exchange is taken from the subsequent email messages.

**Chue (text here from my memory):**

I have app XYZ that does 123. In the app dashboard, I have set up the keyword "123" for search.  My app targets windows 8.1, and does not target Windows 10. From the Windows 8.1 Store App, I can search for "XYZ" and "123" and see my app.  However, when I do this from the Windows 10 store App, I do not get any results. What is wrong?

**MS Support (text after here is from email):**

I understand you are not seeing your app listed in the Win 10 Store. I've taken a closer look and I see that your app is only built for 8 and 8.1. In this situation, you would need to submit a new update that includes a Win 10 package so the Store can begin to offer it.

**Chue:**

Why does the submission process not say anything about this? ... The following is from the help at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt148548.aspx#dist_vis

> Distribution and visibility
>
> By default, your app will be listed in the Store for customers to find via searching, browsing, or a direct link. You can limit the app's availability by choosing a different option in the Distribution and visibility section.
>
> If you don't want the app to be available to any new customers, you can choose Hide this app and stop selling. After the app goes through the certification process, it will no longer be available to new customers (although any customers who already have your app can still use it, and will get any updates that you publish later). You'll still see the app in your dashboard, and if you decide to make it available again, you can do so by creating a new submission and changing its Distribution and visibility setting.
>
> If you want to prevent customers from finding your app in the Store via searching or browsing, but still make it available to a specific group of people, you have a few options. You can choose Hide this app and stop selling and then generate promotional codes to distribute to specific people on Windows 10. They can use the link and code to get your app for free, even though you aren't offering it to any other customers.

**MS Support:**

I do apologize for any misunderstanding. This is not an issue of distribution and availability. Basically, since your app is not built to function on Windows 10 at this time, any customers searching the Store on Windows 10 will not see this app. This is because the app would not run on their system. In this situation, there would be no reason to show them an app they cannot install. Users running Windows 8 and 8.1 are able to search, install and run your app with no issues.

**Chue:**

The app runs fine on Windows 10. I’ve been doing it since the beta of 10.

**MS Support:**

Thanks for the follow up. To clarify, even if the app runs on Win 10, the system will not see it as compatible unless you submit an app package that includes Win 10. This function is the same for any version of Windows. If an app still runs on Win 7, the Store won't list it as available unless the app package is built with a Win 7 version.

Comment: This is incorrect. Windows 10 devices definitely can see Windows 8.x apps in the Windows Store (readily provable: search for "Windows 8" and you'll find several). I suspect that Win10 vs. Win8 app is one of the heuristics used to determine if a specific app should be found. The quoted email may be referring to your app's specific situation or it may be a misunderstanding by the sender, but it definitely does not apply universally. I'll let the dev center escalation team know that this message is (at best) confusing. You might want to reopen your case for clarification.

Comment: @Rob I've added the full support exchange above. You can judge for yourself whether or not there were any misunderstandings by either myself or MS support. The heuristics used for search are a black box, and so I cannot comment on what it is doing. All I can say is that it isn't working for me.

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow up with that team. The explanation you got is completely incorrect. The store knows that older apps are still compatible and will offer them (but not Win 7 apps: Win 7 isn't support Windows Store apps. They were new to Windows 8). Your specific app not showing up in search is a different problem and doesn't generalize to all Windows 8.x apps not showing up.

Comment: @Rob - so some % of Win 8.x apps are showing up in the 10 store. The problem is that we don't know what that % is. Is it 99%, 50%, or 1%? What is the reason for why the x% do not show up? Is it search? Is it compatibility? Is it some other problem? Only MS knows the answers, and at the moment I am getting contradicting info. Is Leonardo's problem the same as my problem? I think it is unclear. My answer above that Win 10 cannot see Win 8 apps is based on what MS Support has said - that Win 8 apps are somehow "incompatible" with Win 10, and is not generalized from my specific search problem.

Comment: I don't know why your app doesn't show up in search, but it's not because it is a Windows 8 app. Why your app doesn't show up in search is a different question than if Windows 10 apps can see Windows 8 apps, and this isn't the right place to discuss your app's search issues. The thread you quote from MS Support here is definitively wrong. I've brought it to the attention of the dev center escalation team and they are reopening your case and should be in contact with you. They may be able to provide more information about why your app doesn't show up in search.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. I believe it is intended to be supported, but you may encounter issues. You need to test it by yourself.

Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps in web browser, and find your app. Right click on the page and select view source. You can find description like

> "Download this app from Microsoft Store for Windows 10, Windows 8,
>   Windows 8.1"

Or

> Download this app from Microsoft Store for Windows 10, Windows 8.

Some windows 8.0 apps/games do work for me.

Comment: I contacted MS support and got contradicting info on this - see my answer below. This seems to be a giant oversight on MS's part.  We all know that Windows 8 apps will run on Windows 10, but MS seems to never have told anybody that Windows 8 only apps will not be in the new store.

Comment: Alan, I didn't find anything like that in page's source. Since I'm having this problem, I'm going to assume @chuex's answer is more helpful. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 users can download Windows 8.x and Windows 10 apps from the store. Windows 10 mobile users can download Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8 apps as well. Basically, anything that was available for Windows 8 will still be available for Windows 10. Anything that was available for Windows Phone 8 will still be available for Windows 10 Mobile.

You don't need to upload packages for each platform you want to target (although it's recommended). The store will pick the best available. Watch the Build Talk [Store: Deep Dive on Publishing Universal Windows Apps](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-710) for more background.

If your users have trouble finding your app when searching the store then you can provide a direct URL for them: https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/. See [View app identity details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt148561.aspx) for more info.

You can find these URLs expanded in your Dev Center Dashboard under App Management/App Identity (this is snipped from a Silverlight only app: it still has a URL for Windows 10 and runs on Windows 10 Mobile):

[image: shared links image]

Comment: You are technically correct in that if a Win 10 user can find my app, that they can download and install it. However, the problem is one of search. Win 10 users cannot find my app either by name or by keyword. It works fine on Windows 8. As for sharing a link, that can only go so far. Ultimately, I need my app to be searchable from the store.

Comment: Yes, but that's a different problem from what Leonardo asked and a very different statement from what you answered. Your app having search problems doesn't generalize to all Windows 8.x apps not being offered. That your app is a Windows 8 app may not be related to your problem at all (the search heuristic is a black box to me too). It is easily demonstrated that some Windows 8 apps can be found by search, so it is definitely wrong to say that Windows 10 will not see any Windows 8.x apps.