# Does 8.1 store/phone apps work on windows 10?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-10-mobile

How windows 8.1 store &phone apps going to run on Windows 10 platform as Windows 8.1 store apps we have charm bar flyouts which are removed from windows 10.How 8.1 apps are going to run under that situation.Also, if I develop Universal app in Windows 10 will it be working on Windows 8.1 platform like if there is anything regarding the backward compatability? I searched a bit I got few answers but none is clearly stated.

Comment: Win 8 apps will work on Win 10. However, the MS Store is not showing any Win 8 apps to Win 10 devices. See [Can Windows 10 download Windows 8.0 app from Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259876/can-windows-10-download-windows-8-0-app-from-store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8.1 Apps will work on Windows 10 , there's a 'App Commands' button in the top-left corner for the charm bar ..

And No, Windows 10 apps 'UWP' will NOT work on Windows 8.1